# Rust struct within struct: borrowing, lifetime, generic types and more total confusion

Tags: struct, rust, borrowing

I'm trying to modify an existing application that forces me to learn rust and it's giving me a hard time (reformulating...)

I would like to have a struct with two fields:

```
pub struct Something<'a> {
    pkt_wtr: PacketWriter<&'a mut Vec<u8>>,
    buf: Vec<u8>,
}
```

Where 'buf' will be used as an io for PacketWriter to write its results. So PacketWriter is something like

```
use std::io::{self};

pub struct PacketWriter<T :io::Write> {
    wtr :T,
}

impl <T :io::Write> PacketWriter<T> {
    pub fn new(wtr :T) -> Self {
        return PacketWriter {
            wtr,
        };
    }
    pub fn into_inner(self) -> T {
        self.wtr
    }
    pub fn write(&mut self) {
        self.wtr.write_all(&[10,11,12]).unwrap();
        println!("wrote packet");
    }
}
```

Then inside 'Something' I want to use PacketWriter this way: let it write what it needs in 'buf' and drain it by pieces.

```
impl Something<'_> {
    pub fn process(&mut self) {
        self.pkt_wtr.write();
        let c = self.buf.drain(0..1);
    }
}
```

What seems to be impossible is to create a workable constructor for 'Something'

```
impl Something<'_> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let mut buf = Vec::new();
        let pkt_wtr = PacketWriter::new(&mut buf);        
        return Something {
            pkt_wtr: pkt_wtr,
            buf: buf,
        };
    }
}
```

What does not seem to be doable is, however I try, to have PacketWriter being constructed on a borrowed reference from 'buf' while 'buf' is also stored in the 'Something' object.

I can give 'buf' fully to 'PacketWriter' (per example below) but I cannot then access the content of 'buf' later. I know that it works in the example underneath, but it's because I can have access to the 'buf' after it is given to the "PacketWriter' (through 'wtr'). In reality, the 'PacketWriter' has that field (wtr) private and in addition it's a code that I cannot modify to, for example, obtain a getter for 'wtr'

Thanks

I wrote a small working program to describe the intent and the problem, with the two options

```
use std::io::{self};

pub struct PacketWriter<T :io::Write> {
    wtr :T,
}

impl <T :io::Write> PacketWriter<T> {
    pub fn new(wtr :T) -> Self {
        return PacketWriter {
            wtr,
        };
    }
    pub fn into_inner(self) -> T {
        self.wtr
    }
    pub fn write(&mut self) {
        self.wtr.write_all(&[10,11,12]).unwrap();
        println!("wrote packet");
    }
}

/*
// that does not work of course because buf is local but this is not the issue
pub struct Something<'a> {
    pkt_wtr: PacketWriter<&'a mut Vec<u8>>,
    buf: Vec<u8>,
}

impl Something<'_> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let mut buf = Vec::new();
        let pkt_wtr = PacketWriter::new(&mut buf);
        //let mut pkt_wtr = PacketWriter::new(buf);     
        return Something {
            pkt_wtr,
            buf,
        };
    }
    pub fn process(&mut self) {
        self.pkt_wtr.write();
        println!("process {:?}", self.buf);
    }
}
*/

pub struct Something {
    pkt_wtr: PacketWriter<Vec<u8>>,
}

impl Something {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let pkt_wtr = PacketWriter::new(Vec::new());
        return Something {
            pkt_wtr,
        };
    }
    pub fn process(&mut self) {
        self.pkt_wtr.write();
        let file = &mut self.pkt_wtr.wtr;
        println!("processing Something {:?}", file);            
        let c = file.drain(0..1);
        println!("Drained {:?}", c);
    }
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut file = Vec::new();
    let mut wtr = PacketWriter::new(&mut file);

    wtr.write();

    println!("Got data {:?}", file);
    {
        let c = file.drain(0..2);
        println!("Drained {:?}", c);     
    } 
    println!("Remains {:?}", file);
    
    let mut data = Something::new();
    data.process();

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: The code you've given compiles fine for me. Even if I try to do a mutable borrow where you left the comment (say, `let x = &mut self.pkt_wtr.wtr`), it still works fine. What is it you want to do with `self.pkt_wtr.wtr` that Rust won't allow?

Comment: Sorry, I did not make clear that the PacketWriter module is non-accessible in the real code so its 'wtr' is private and I cannot modify it to make a getter of some kind. All I have is a into_inner that returns 'self.wtr' so it does not help.

Comment: What I don't understand is why I can't keep access to the initial writer object (that I call buf) as I'm the owner while giving it to the PacketWriter. But I can't find a way to build a PacketWriter from a reference to that buffer/object *and* keep it (building a PacketWriter from a reference to a Vec<u8> works fine, it's just I can't seem to be able to build it *and* store in one of the Something's strict fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarification, I found a solution using Rc+RefCell or Arc+Mutex. I encapsulated the buffer in a Rc/RefCell and added a Write

```
pub struct WrappedWriter {
    data :Arc<Mutex<Vec<u8>>>,
}

impl WrappedWriter {
    pub fn new(data : Arc<Mutex<Vec<u8>>>) -> Self {
        return WrappedWriter {
            data,
        };
    }
}    

impl Write for WrappedWriter {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> Result<usize, Error> {
        let mut data = self.data.lock().unwrap();
        data.write(buf)
    }
    fn flush(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

pub struct Something {
    wtr: PacketWriter<WrappedWriter>,
    data : Arc<Mutex<Vec<u8>>>,
}

impl Something {
    pub fn new() -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let data :Arc<Mutex<Vec<u8>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));
        let wtr = PacketWriter::new(WrappedWriter::new(Arc::clone(&data)));

        return Ok(PassthroughDecoder {
            wtr,
            data,
        });
    }

    pub fn process(&mut self) {
         let mut data = self.data.lock().unwrap();
         data.clear();
    }
}
```

You can replace Arc by Rc and Mutex by RefCell if you don't have thread-safe issues in which case the reference access becomes

```
let data = self.data.borrow_mut();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what the question is, given that the code appears to compile, but I can take a stab at one part: why can't you use `into_inner()` on `self.wtr` inside the `process` function?

`into_inner` takes ownership of the `PacketWriter` that gets passed into its `self` parameter. (You can tell this because the [parameter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#defining-methods) is spelled `self`, rather than `&self` or `&mut self`.) Taking ownership means that it is consumed: it cannot be used anymore by the caller and the callee is responsible for dropping it (read: running destructors). After taking ownership of the `PacketWriter`, the `into_inner` function returns just the `wtr` field and drops (runs destructors on) the rest. But where does that leave the `Something` struct? It has a field that needs to contain a `PacketWriter`, and you just took its `PacketWriter` away and destroyed it! The function ends, and the value held in the `PacketWriter` field is unknown: it can't be thing that was in there from the beginning, because that was taken over by `into_inner` and destroyed. But it also can't be anything else.

Rust generally forbids structs from having uninitialized or undefined fields. You need to have that field defined at all times.

Here's the worked example:

```rust
pub fn process(&mut self) {
    self.pkt_wtr.write();

    // There's a valid PacketWriter in pkt_wtr

    let raw_wtr: Vec<u8> = self.pkt_wtr.into_inner();

    // The PacketWriter in pkt_wtr was consumed by into_inner!
    // We have a raw_wtr of type Vec<u8>, but that's not the right type for pkt_wtr

    // We could try to call this function here, but what would it do?
    self.pkt_wtr.write();

    println!("processing Something");
}
```

(Note: The example above has slightly squishy logic. Formally, because you don't own `self`, you can't do anything that would take ownership of any part of it, even if you put everything back neatly when you're done.)

You have a few options to fix this, but with one major caveat: with the public interface you have described, there is *no way* to get access to the `PacketWriter::wtr` field and put it back into the same `PacketWriter`. You'll have to extract the `PacketWriter::wtr` field and put it into a new `PacketWriter`.

Here's one way you could do it. Remember, the goal is to have `self.packet_wtr` defined at all times, so we'll use a function called [`mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) to put a dummy `PacketWriter` into `self.pkt_wtr`. This ensures that `self.pkt_wtr` always has *something* in it.

```rust
pub fn process(&mut self) {
    self.pkt_wtr.write();

    // Create a new dummy PacketWriter and swap it with self.pkt_wtr
    // Returns an owned version of pkt_wtr that we're free to consume
    let pkt_wtr_owned = std::mem::replace(&mut self.pkt_wtr, PacketWriter::new(Vec::new()));

    // Consume pkt_wtr_owned, returning its wtr field
    let raw_wtr = pkt_wtr_owned.into_inner();

    // Do anything you want with raw_wtr here -- you own it.
    println!("The vec is: {:?}", &raw_wtr);

    // Create a new PacketWriter with the old PacketWriter's buffer.
    // The dummy PacketWriter is dropped here.
    self.pkt_wtr = PacketWriter::new(raw_wtr);

    println!("processing Something");
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=33ae310e20b8770ad793884028140f84)

This solution is definitely a hack, and it's potentially a place where the borrow checker could be improved to realize that leaving a field temporarily undefined is fine, as long as it's not accessed before it is assigned again. (Though there may be an edge case I missed; this stuff is hard to reason about in general.) Additionally, this is the kind of thing that can be optimized away by later compiler passes through [dead store elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_store).

If this turns out to be a hotspot when profiling, there are `unsafe` techniques that would allow the field to be invalid for that period, but that would probably need a new question.

However, my recommendation would be to find a way to get an "escape hatch" function added to `PacketWriter` that lets you do exactly what you want to do: get a mutable reference to the inner `wtr` without taking ownership of `PacketWriter`.

```rust
impl<T: io::Write> PacketWriter<T> {
    pub fn inner_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        &mut self.wtr
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I think I'm starting to understand. In general, to rephrase the question, ideally I'd like to have a struct with two fields: a 'buf' of type Vec<u8> and a 'pkt_wtr' whose constructor uses a reference to that same 'buf'. I think that I've now understood that no matter what I do, when I call the constructor of 'pkt-wtr', then because the result of the new() is sharing the same lifetime than one of its parameters, then I'm stuck, rust will consider that new() has borrowed it. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, essentially. Formally, `new` will take ownership of whatever you give it, and if you give it a reference, it takes ownership of that reference, including the responsibility to not outlive the thing the reference points to. That makes it really tricky to do the two fields that you want, because you end up with a self-referential struct, which can be expressed but is probably more trouble than its worth.

Comment: At the end, the copy cannot work because the struct has other inner items that where initialized and I cannot restore them. So I'll find a wau to add "inner_mut" method - Thanks!